# Intellij confuses Y and Z

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm used to deleting a line with `CTRL+Y` and reverting a change with `CTRL+Z`. But on my machine, Intellij removes the line, when I press `CTRL+Z` instead.

I beleive it has something to do with a german layout/keyboard. Because they have y and z switched.

I set the layout to US, so it should not be a problem. When I press Y it really prints Y, but Intellij still interprets `CTRL+Y` as reverting last change.

Answer (score 22):

It depends on the order of the keyboard layouts in your system.

Idea uses the top/first layout and does not care about the currently selected keyboard layout.

**Solution**: Just put the non-english layout to the top in your system settings.

**Hint** (depending on the question that leads to a QWERTZ keyboard):

- [KDE, de] Systemeinstellungen -> Eingabegeräte -> Tastatur -> Belegungen -> Belegungen einrichten
- [KDE, en] System settings -> Input devices -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Configure Layouts

Comment: I cannot upvote this enough, you have saved an entire office full of German programmers here :-)

Comment: Man, this bugged me for ages. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your keymap and make sure the Undo action is set to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>. Likewise search for Delete line in the keymap and make sure it is set appropriately. Here is a screen shot of the Undo action (I am on a Mac so mine uses command key).

[image]

Comment: Well, yes I can change the shortcuts for these 2 command, but there can be more. When I reassign the combination and press CTRL+Y (in english layout), Intellij shows me CTRL+Y. How can it be?